# Black screen when installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation

I am installing the desktop version of Ubuntu 20.04. This is a fresh install on a formatted drive using a USB stick.

When I start the install process it goes into Ubuntu but then I get a black screen. It briefly gives an Ubuntu sign and then black screen again.

I ran it in safe mode and then it installed. When it reboots I get a black screen again.

When I run it in safe mode, it works but the resolution is limited to 800x400 and I have to run it in safe mode every time it boots.
It is an Intel I7 64 bit with onboard graphics

To add on to this, I tried to format the drive and re-install, now I get a fatal error "Ëxicuting 'grub-instal/dev/sda' failed".

Comment: I solved the issue with regards to the error "Exicuting 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed". My hard drive seems to have become locked for some reason. Installing on a new hard drive but still with safe graphics. No solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was the Motherboard had come from a system that had a built in display. My black screen was due to it not giving output to the HDMI. VGA display could pick up that it was a secondary display. Changed the display settings in Ubuntu using the VGA display and now it is working.